# Print the variable assignment as output

Tags: python, variables

I have probably a really simple question: Is it possible to print the value of a variable assignment without reentering the variable name?

I mean, when we enter let's say:

```
foo = 5
```

We get the following output:

```
5
```

I tried things like `foo = 5;`  (as if I was using MATLAB - actually it hides the output) but, couldn't find any character that does this. Even in the tutorials I looked that, this was not mentioned.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I have many many local variables. In my code, I need to append, vstack etc. them. It would be quite good, if I could get the assigned values during debugging, without reentering the variable name (I am not using any development environment like Eclipse).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible in Python.  Variable assignments do not return anything:

```
>>> print(exec("a = 1"))
None
>>> a
1
>>>
```

Comment: OK, thanks. Apparently, that was the reason why I could not find anything about it...

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get to have this is to create a class overriding the __setattr__ method.

```
class A():
    def __setattr__(self,name,value):
        print(value)
        self.__dict__['name'] = 1
a = A()
a.x = 1
1
```